# How to make a nest loop to loop through 2 phone numbers?

Tags: javascript

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("..."),
"name" : "jrose",
"phonenumbers" : [
{
    "type" : "home",
    "value" : "18005550000"
},
{
    "type" : "work",
    "value" : "18004339919"
}],
"callerId" : ["..."],
"PIN" : "...",
"useSMS" : true
}
```

This was created in mongodb, if you were curious. I was just wondering what the nested for loop would look like to loop through these two numbers.

Comment: Nested loops are for when you have an array inside another array. There's only one array, so just a single loop is needed.

Comment: Very unclear question. Tell us what you're about to do with the numbers. Otherwise, refer to for loop and string manipulation references.

Answer (score 0):

`phonenumbers` is simply an array containing objects, so iterate the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < doc.phonenumbers.length; i++) {
    console.log(doc.phonenumbers[i].value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this using `forEach`, assuming your current object is in a variable named `obj`:

```
obj.phonenumbers.forEach(function(number) {
    // loop body
    console.log(number.value);
});
```